# My function should return matching pairs of values, but returns one matching pair and one unmatched pair

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a function that takes a number of collisions and two samples of speeds of particles: it's supposed to take a pair of particles (one from each sample), calculate the kinetic energy of each particle, find the difference between the energies (absolute value), then add half the difference to the lower energy particle and subtract half the difference from the higher energy particle, making them exactly the same, and then calculating the speeds of the collided particles which should also be the same. For some reason, running the program with two collisions, the first pair of resulting energies dont match, whilst the second pair two. I can't see why! Any help is appreciated!!

```
samp1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
samp2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]


def prac(ncoll, samp1, samp2):
    m = 4*pc.u
    sp1 = []
    sp2 = []
    for i in range(ncoll):
        a = random.choices(samp1)
        b = random.choices(samp2)
        sp1.append(a)
        sp2.append(b)
    np.concatenate(sp1)
    np.concatenate(sp2)
    en1 = 0.5*m*np.square(sp1)
    en2 = 0.5*m*np.square(sp2)
    diff = (en1-en2)
    absdiff = np.abs(diff)
    halfen = 0.5*absdiff
    if diff[i] >= 0:
        finalen1 = en1[i] - halfen
        finalen2 = en2[i] + halfen
    else:
        finalen1 = en1[i] + halfen
        finalen2 = en2[i] - halfen
    finalsp1 = np.sqrt((2*finalen1)/m)
    finalsp2 = np.sqrt((2*finalen2)/m)
    return finalsp1, finalsp2


print(prac(2, samp1, samp2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is what you are looking for. Change the following portion from:

```
if diff[i] >= 0:
    finalen1 = en1[i] - halfen
    finalen2 = en2[i] + halfen
else:
    finalen1 = en1[i] + halfen
    finalen2 = en2[i] - halfen
finalsp1 = np.sqrt((2*finalen1)/m)
finalsp2 = np.sqrt((2*finalen2)/m)
return finalsp1, finalsp2
```

to:

```
finalsp1, finalsp2 = [], []
for i in range(ncoll):
    if diff[i] >= 0:
        finalen1 = en1[i] - halfen[i]
        finalen2 = en2[i] + halfen[i]
    else:
        finalen1 = en1[i] + halfen[i]
        finalen2 = en2[i] - halfen[i]
    finalsp1.append(np.sqrt((2*finalen1)/m))
    finalsp2.append(np.sqrt((2*finalen2)/m))

return finalsp1, finalsp2
```

The 'for' loop was missing in the above case which means 'i' was at the nth column number from previous iteration.

Comment: finalsp1 and finalsp2 are not indentified if I change to yours, since that;s the first time they're mentioned.

Comment: Oh yeah, just declare two empty lists just above the for loop as, finalsp1, finalsp2 = [], []

Comment: Actually after a bit of a think and a play around I know what you were  intending, and it's cleared the issue up for me! Thanks a lot man!!